# Angular CLI not bundling additional scripts

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to add additional script to my angular cli project but it is not bundling them, it just add them without uglify, minify and concatenate.

This is my .angular-cli.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "moboz"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

and this is the output html with `ng build --prod`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Moboz</title>
  <base href="/MobileTest/dist/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.3ffb23a658d7dce546e3.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.f52c146b4f7d1751829e.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.3623d6a4bac4a30763a7.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.f634e30476f1ba6b31c3.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Why isn't it bundling it?